# Getting 404 When Try To Enter My Website With Only Android

Tags: android, web

I can enter to my website from **most of android phones and all computers.** But when some android devices try to enter to my website, (*example my phone and very few of my visitors*) **getting 404**. And in my **another** website opening with **no css styles** in my phone.

Don't know why; when I open `"Request desktop site"` setting, can enter to my website with no error.

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark here...  Is your droid phone perhaps tacking on a default page name that doesn't exist?  I.e., is your phone requesting "index.html", but your site actually has an "index.php"?

404 means "File not found", so that would indicate that it's requesting a specific file that can't be found.  The situation above would cause that.

Comment: tested your example. In my phone, http://mywebsite.com/k  adress is subfolder contains a tool for my visitors and getting 404. And http://mywebsite.com/k/.index.php too getting same error. And I'm sure about k folder has an index.php file.

Comment: "When I open "Request desktop site" setting, can enter to my website with no error."...  I am assuming this means that you have a mobile version of your site that's being accessed by your phone, but also have a link that enables a mobile user to access the full site?  Also, are you saying that the full site is actually working in your Android browser, and that only the mobile version is not working?  Have you tried clearing the browser history on your phone and/or (I know, I know) powering it down and back on?